# How to get Magento version in Magento2 ? (Equivalent of Mage::getVersion())

Tags: magento2, version, semantic-versioning

How do I get the Magento version in Magento2.x (e.g. `2.0.0`) ?

In Magento1.x, I could do it with

```
Mage::getVersion()
```

So what's the equivalent in Magento2.x ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Up until Magento version 2.0.7 the version number was maintained in the [`AppInterface::VERSION`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0.7/app/code/Magento/Backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/footer.phtml) constant.

With the release of Magento 2.1 the constant was removed.

So till 2.0.7 if you check the [adminhtml footer file](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0.7/app/code/Magento/Backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/footer.phtml) where the version is shown

[image: Admin Panel Footer]

It had reference to the [`\Magento\Framework\AppInterface::VERSION`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0.7/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/AppInterface.php#L20) constant.

But since Magento 2.1 release the [footer file](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1.0/app/code/Magento/Backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/footer.phtml) now uses the [`\Magento\Backend\Block\Page\Footer->getMagentoVersion()`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Backend/Block/Page/Footer.php#L52) which in turn calls the [`\Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadata->getVersion()`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1.0/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/ProductMetadata.php#L62).

Previously the `ProductMetadata->getVersion()` used to return the value of the constant `\Magento\Framework\AppInterface::VERSION`, but now it parses the `composer.json` as well as `composer.lock` and returns the appropriate magento version

So no matter which version you are on either 2.0.x or 2.1.x, if you use the `\Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadata->getVersion()` method, you will always get the proper Magento version.

**Conclusion:**

Magento 1:

```
Mage::getVersion() //will return the magento version
```

Magento 2:

```
//Updated to use object manager
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productMetadata = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadataInterface');
$version = $productMetadata->getVersion(); //will return the magento version
```

Comment: `composer.json` might contain a version constraint like "^2.1" which doesn't indicate the exact version, so Magento is (also) checking the `composer.lock` file to see what exact version is currently installed.

Comment: @7ochem thanks for the information, updated the answer as well :)

Answer (score 22):

You can use this in 2.0.x versions:

```
echo \Magento\Framework\AppInterface::VERSION;
```

For version 2.1:

Way 1, using DI:

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadataInterface $productMetadata
) {
    $this->productMetadata = $productMetadata;
}

public function getMagentoVersion()
{
    return $this->productMetadata->getVersion();
}
```

Way 2, using ObjectManager directly:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productMetadata = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadataInterface');
echo $productMetadata->getVersion();
```

Comment: Such implementation you can find at *app/code/Magento/Backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/footer.phtml*

Comment: NOTE: this does NO LONGER work for Magento 2.1+ (see other answers!)

Comment: other answer actually work? In my case through error report. See my new answer.

Comment: See https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/197840/43030

Answer (score 13):

On top of the other answers, you can get the major version (for example 2.1) by **accessing `/magento_version` on your Magento 2 website.**

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Seems like a security leak to me: this is a great way for hackers to find vulnerable Magento 2 sites! Of course, you only seem to be able to get the major and minor version this way, but it still seems like a bad idea.

Comment: great "quick & dirty" trick, thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Mentioned solutions are not applicable starting from Magento 2.1 **(`\Magento\Framework\AppInterface::VERSION` constant was removed)**

The new way to get version is to retrieve it from Product Metadata Instance (reads version from composer.json):

```
$productMetadata = new \Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadata();
$version = $productMetadata->getVersion();
```

(better to inject Product Metadata to constructor as `\Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadataInterface`)

Answer (score 7):

You can run below command to get the magento version:

```
php bin/magento --version
```

Comment: it seems that this doesn't differentiate Community vs. Enterprise editions of Magento

Answer (score 6):

In case someone has to find it manually. The base Magento module version is located in this composer file:

```
vendor/magento/magento2-base/composer.json
```

Also as suggested above, to make below code work:

```
$productMetadata = new \Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadata();
$version = $productMetadata->getVersion();
```

`\Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadata` now requires instance of `ComposerJsonFinder` to be passed at the time of instantiation.

An example I found in `dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/Composer/ComposerInformationTest.php`:

```
$directories = [
    DirectoryList::CONFIG => [DirectoryList::PATH => __DIR__ . '/_files/'],
    DirectoryList::ROOT => [DirectoryList::PATH => __DIR__ . '/_files/' . $composerDir],
    DirectoryList::COMPOSER_HOME => [DirectoryList::PATH => __DIR__ . '/_files/' . $composerDir],
];

$this->directoryList = $this->objectManager->create(
    'Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList',
    ['root' => __DIR__ . '/_files/' . $composerDir, 'config' => $directories]
);

$this->composerJsonFinder = new ComposerJsonFinder($this->directoryList);
```

Above code is purely for informational purposes. You have to dig in more to make it work.

Answer (score 4):

**For unix like users**

No need to write any PHP code for this. Because Magento 2 utilises composer it makes it all easier. You can do this two ways:

Check the composer.json and look for a key called version.
If you're like me who likes to use the terminal you can do something like on the root of the project.

```
composer licenses | grep Version:
```

This returns the version of the M2 if you want to check wether its a community or a enterprise version then just do the following:

```
composer licenses | grep Name:
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php echo __('Magento'); ?>
<?php  echo __('ver. %1', \Magento\Framework\AppInterface::VERSION) ?>
```

For version 2.1:

```
<?php
$productMetadata = new \Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadata();
$version = $productMetadata->getVersion();
?>
<?php  echo __('ver. %1', $version) ?>
```

Comment: Does only work for 2.0.x, see:  https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/96865/13642

Answer (score 1):

simply check composer.json file on magento2 root, you'll find text like this

```
"version": "2.1.2",
```

Comment: `composer.json` might contain a version constraint like "^2.1" which doesn't indicate the exact version. You should check the `composer.lock` file to see what exact version is currently installed.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ways to check Magento version

#### Method #1: Use PHP Code checking

Check Magento 1 version

```
Mage::getVersion() //will return the magento version
```

Check Magento 2 version

You can use this in 2.0.x versions:

```
echo \Magento\Framework\AppInterface::VERSION;
```

For version 2.1:

The first way, using DI:

```
public function __construct( \Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadataInterface $productMetadata ) { 
    $this->productMetadata = $productMetadata; 
} 
public function getMagentoVersion() { 
    return $this->productMetadata->getVersion(); 
}
```

The second way, using ObjectManager directly:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$productMetadata = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadataInterface'); 
echo $productMetadata->getVersion();
```

#### Method #2: Check Magento version via command line

You can run the below command to get the Magento 2 version:

```
php bin/magento --version
```

Actually, since Magento 2 has utilized its composer so that you do not need to write any PHP code for this. Instead, there are two options to find Magento 2 version:

Firstly, please try out the composer.json and look for version keyword. Should you prefer using terminal, you can add something on the root of project.

```
composer licenses | grep Version:
```

Another way to check Magento 2 version weather it is community or enterprise edition, please write the following

```
composer licenses | grep Name:
```

Use web service to check https://www.mageplaza.com/check-magento-version/