# How to enable my bugfix extension to run in a specific Magento 2 version?

Tags: magento2, composer, third-party-module

I'm creating a module in order to fix a bug in Magento 2.3.0 that will be part of the next release. So, I would like to restrict via Composer the dependencies of that module.

How can I restrict my module to run just with the Magento 2.3.0?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96858/how-to-get-magento-version-in-magento2-equivalent-of-magegetversion find the Magento version and execute your code if you find compatible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the Magento 2 version and run it when it's the version that you want, if not you can add a log warning to show a message like this example:

```
if($this->helper->getVersion() !== self::MAGENTO_COMPATIBLE_VERSION){
    $this->logger->emergency('You are using a updated Magento version ' . Data::AMASTY_MODULE_NAME .'. Please check the module MyCompany_HotFix compatibility!' );
}
```

**Reference:**

[How to check the Magento 2 version?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/96858/16416)

[How to use logger?](https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-write-log-magento-2.html)

Comment: Hello Rafael, Is there any functionality like that if Magento 2.3.x run then php version 7.2 will set or if Magento 2.2.x run then php version 7.0 will set.